# How to generate a matrix of bode plots?

Tags: python, matlab, python-2.7, matplotlib, matlab-figure

I have multiple bode plots and would like to draw them in a compact way to ease visual evaluation. I thought of sth. like an nxm matrix plot. However, I could not find out how to realize that either in Matlab or Python. Any suggestions helping me to implement this are highly appreciated.

Some example data to be used for generating two of the bode plots.

```
f1=[1,10,100,1000] Hz
amp1=[12,56,89,100] V
phase1=[0, 90,180,270] deg

f2=[1,20,50,100] Hz
amp2=[16,34,76,90] V
phase2=[10, 45,145,160] deg
```

Comment: do you already have the frequency response arrays or they are separate models ? Can you add an example ? For MIMO systems this is done autoamtically anyways.

Comment: I have n frequency response arrays (where each of which consists of a frequency, magnitude and phase vector) of the same  signal capured at n different operating conditons.

Comment: Then you can create an FRD object and simply use bode

Comment: That's interesting. Could you please explain how to generate one FRD object if I have three vectors storing frequency, magnitude and phase? Perhaps as an answer so that I can accept it afterwards...

Comment: added a template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you can supply your frequency response arrays as input output responses of a MIMO system. Let's fake some 3x4x100 complex numbers, and fake a range of frequencies and then draw the Bode

```
A = rand(3,4,1000);
A = A + (rand(3,4,1000)-0.5)*1i;
w = logspace(-2,2,1000);
G = frd(A,w);
bode(G)
```

You can obtain the complex vectors back again from mag/phase arrays with the polar representation of `r*exp(i \theta)` with magnitude and phase angle.

[image]

---

**FOR THE EDIT**

```
f1=[1,10,100,1000];
amp1=[12,56,89,100];
phase1=[0, 90,180,270];

f2=[1,20,50,100];
amp2=[16,34,76,90];
phase2=[10, 45,145,160];

resp1 = amp1.*exp(1i*phase1*pi/180);
resp2 = amp2.*exp(1i*phase2*pi/180);

G = frd(resp1,f1,'FrequencyUnit','Hz');
H = frd(resp2,f2,'FrequencyUnit','Hz');

bode(G,H);

subplot(211);
bode(G);
hold on;
subplot(212);
bode(H);
```

Comment: Sorry, I'am not a Matlab programmer. I have vectors as follows: f1=[...], amp1=[...], phase1=[...], ..., fn=[...], amp_n=[...], phase_n=[...]. How to combine that with your template?

Comment: @Rickson Hmm, I think I don't follow. Can you make a few dummy arrays with 3 4 elements in them just to demonstrate structure in your question edit? Then I can copy them and modify my answer

Comment: Encountered a problem... The bode plot shows the correct magnitude but the wrong phase. May your formula `resp = amp.*exp(1i*phase)` be incorrect since I have provided phase angle in deg and not rad?

Comment: @Rickson Ah yes probably, didn't check rigorously to be honest.

Answer (score 1):

Multiple bode plots on the same axes:

```
bode(sys)
hold on
bode(sys2)
```

Subplots:

```
subplot(211);
bode(sys1);
hold on;
subplot(212);
bode(sys2);
hold on;
subplot(211);
bode(sys3);
```

Not sure what you're asking beyond that.

Comment: I don't have any model (sys). Only the data arrays. Simulink is not available as well.

Comment: Do you want subplots or multiple bode plots displayed on the same axes? Either way, there's nothing magical about bode plots if you already have the frequency vs magnitude and phase plots. Just do subplot(211) plot(frequency, magnitude) subplot(212) plot(frequency, phase)

Comment: Thx. Need to have subplots (like a matrix plot).